# Windows 11 stuttering

Tags: performance, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-11, nvidia-geforce, nvidia

Recently, I began experiencing short stutters in Windows 11. I'm a dummy when it comes to troubleshooting operating systems, so I would appreciate some guidance or anything. Here are my findings so far:

**The problem**

- Less-than-a-second stutter every 8-10 seconds
- Happens in most apps (Firefox, certain games, Explorer...)
- Does not happen in full-screen apps (YouTube in full screen, most games)
- Does not happen if I have the NVidia Control Panel open in the screen with the 3D logo spinning (weird, but it's... something)
- Mouse and typing not affected (though text and clicks are affected if the app receiving them is)
- "System" process bumps to 5-10% CPU for a few seconds after it happens.
- I believe it started when I updated NVidia GeForce Experience (I've already tried uninstalling it)

**Hardware**

```
Dell Inspiron 7572  
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
16GB RAM, 1TB HD, 512GB SSD
NVidia GeForce MX150 (driver 528.02 01/05/2023)
```

**Operating System**

```
Windows 11 Home Single Language
Version 22H2 (build 22621.963)
```

**What I've tried** (or not and why) (none of them worked)

- Updating Windows and NVidia drivers
- Uninstalling NVidia FrameView thing
- Uninstalling NVidia GeForce Experience
- My GPU doesn't support NVidia overlays so that's not it
- I don't have a restoration point to rollback the Windows update, since I've seen around the internet that 22H2 has a similar issue
- Rolling back NVidia software and driver versions
- Event Viewer shows some errors, but nothing at the same rate the stutter happens
- Running various Windows troubleshooting programs and guides
- Rebooting many times, safe mode, disable anti-virus real time protection, standard troubleshooting stuff...

Thanks for reading, any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try DISM / SFC and see if that helps.    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion! I've already ran all these as I found on the internet, ran again to be extra sure, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

If DISM / SFC did not work and you said you tried them twice, then now:

(1) Update ALL drivers including BIOS (UEFI).

then

(2) Run a Windows 11 Repair Install and Keep Everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select download. When the download is complete, run it and This will launch the Repair.  You need a USB Key for this step.

Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything. Use the Default Keep Everything.

If Repair does not work, then at a convenient spot, it will be worthwhile to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I installed the latest Dell BIOS driver, downloaded Windows 11 and followed the instructions, but the problem persists :(
Guess I'll have to live with it until some future update (from whatever is causing it) fixes it.

Comment: Do a repair install as I suggested.  That should fix the problem. A future update may or may not. Best to repair the issue instead of waiting.

Comment: I should note that I have 2 Windows 11 Pro V22H2 production machines and 1 Windows 11 Pro V22H2+ Insider machine and zero stuttering or halting. Make sure your Windows is running on the SSD as Drive C.

Comment: Yes I did the repair install, took quite a few minutes. It's annoying because it started a few days ago, so I'm not questioning Windows or you, it's just annoying.

Comment: There is no endemic reason why this stuttering occurs.  You made a number of changes so at a convenient time, it may be best to back up and re-install Windows.